# How to detemine the docker entrypoint with snapshot builds?

Tags: java, gradle, docker

Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate question.  It probably is, but I can't find what I'm looking for.

We have a CI pipeline that uses gradle to build our Java project, and we need to dockerize it.  As part of the pipeline, the software version is constantly being updated.  So, when we copy (or add) the tar file to the docker image, it requires a wildcard search, which I can do.  However, because of how gradle builds the tar files, the entrypoint also needs a software version in it.  I can't figure out how to get the entrypoint to generate on the fly when I build my docker image.

Since that might not make a whole lot of sense, here's my current dockerfile:

```
# This is the base image
FROM internal_server/java8

# location of the working directories
VOLUME /tmp

# Add the gradle distribution to the container and untar it
# The actual name of the tar file will be of the form 
# package-version-snapshot.tar
COPY build/distributions/package-*.tar package.tar
RUN tar xvf package.tar

# This is a gradle convention, the script that runs the program,
# in our case, will have the same name as the tar file
ENTRYPOINT ["package/bin/package"]
```

Note that in the copy command I used a wildcard search.  This gives me the tar file while ignoring the version number.  How do I do the same thing with the entrypoint?  Or, alternatively, how do I export the file name in a form that the rest of the dockerfile can use?

I can get the full path by doing something like

```
RUN export FILE_NAME=`find ./ -name rmob-boundaries -type f`
```

but I can't docker to recognize it.  Doing something like

```
RUN echo $FILE_NAME

ENTRYPOINT ["$FILE_NAME"]
```

doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT 1:** Tried the first comment.  Doing something like

```
RUN export FILE_NAME=`find ./ -name package -type f`

ENTRYPOINT $FILE_NAME
```

Doesn't work.  The docker image builds, but docker run just...doesn't do anything.  I think because the variable FILE_NAME is left undefined, and when it's run as a shell, it just tries to execute a non-existent command and fails.

**EDIT 2:** Here is what I think the essence of the problem is.  Let's say I execute the following commands:

```
RUN export FILE_NAME=`find ./ -name package -type f`; echo $FILE_NAME
RUN echo $FILE_NAME
```

The first line, the set of run commands successfully exports the variable and prints it to std out, but in the second run command, it prints out nothing.  So even though I've exported the correct value, it must be executing in a sub shell (kind of a guess) because the value can't be seen by any other RUN method.  In this case, the entrypoint fails no matter how I implement it.

If, however, I do the following:

```
ENV FILE_NAME `find ./ -name package -type f`
RUN echo $FILE_NAME
```

What is saved in the variable is the actual text string, not the evaluation of it like you would expect in bash.  The echo does work, but what it prints out is `find ./ -name package -type f` as the value of the variable.  Also, in this case, the entrypoint also fails when I try to run the program.

Comment: I believe the square bracket syntax doesn't expand variables. Have you tried the plain shell syntax? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: Have you tried this variant? That documentation says : .... execute a shell directly, for example: ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "echo", "$HOME" ]. Variables that are defined in the Dockerfileusing ENV, will be substituted by the Dockerfile parser.

Comment: Did you try `ENV FILE_NAME `find ./ -name package -type f`` instead of your `RUN export FILE_NAME=`find ./ -name package -type f``